# How can I use XSL to run a template against a specific node that is located by an attribute?

Tags: xpath, xslt

For example, I'm trying to pick out the value "Application Library" from the following XML - ie, the value under content-node/localedata/title, where localedata@locale = "en".

```
<content-node objectid="6_NO2UF4I1186E1026H4BLVI08F1">
       <localedata locale="de">
            <title>Anwendungsbibliothek</title>
        </localedata>
        <localedata locale="en">
            <title>Application Library</title>
        </localedata>
        <localedata locale="es">
            <title>Biblioteca de aplicaciones</title>
        </localedata>
</content-node>
```

Specifically, what XPath expression do I put in the xsl:template@match value? I think it should be something like this, except I don't know how to match for the hardcoded value "en":

```
<xsl:template match="localedata[@locale = en]">
```

Am I on the right track here, or is there some other way I should go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, you should be on the right track. I can't seem to find any samples to verify and confirm this - but you should have no trouble trying and verifying this.

I say : go for it!

Looks like you'll have to adapt your XSL just a tiny bit:

```
<xsl:template match="localedata[@locale='en']">
```

With this (remove spaces after @locale, put the value in ' ... ') everything should be fine.

Marc

Comment: Thanks. That formatting worked.... I hadn't been able to find a demonstrative example of it either.